# How to get Visual Studio to recognize the tests in my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

We just converted all our NUnit Test projects to MSTest.  We have multiple tests projects.  When doing a Run All Tests in Solution from Visual Studio, it only runs one project.  How do you make Visual Studio recognize the other test projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the MS Test runner does not recognize test projects is that it needs a test project type in the .csproj file.  It was originally created as a class project for NUnit instead of as a MsTest project.  This needs to be added in the .csproj file:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if all of your test are loaded in "Test List Editor" (you can access that by double-click on "AutomatedTests.vsmdi" from "Solution Items" from you Solution)